# JAX RS, test ETags with JAX RS Client API, Jersey, Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs, etag

I always get `java.text.ParseException: End of header.` exception.

```
 @GET
    public Response getTemplate4CustomSkin(@Context final Request request)
    {
        EntityTag eTag = new EntityTag("123456789");
        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = request.evaluatePreconditions(eTag);
        if (responseBuilder == null)
        {
            System.out.printf("is null");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("is not null");
        }
        return Response.ok(data.inputStream, data.mimeType).tag(eTag).build();
    }
 }

    @Test
    public void testGetFileEtagIsNotChanged() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("someUrl");
        EntityTag eTag = new EntityTag("123456789");
        Response response = target.request().get();
        //send request 2nd time with 
        response = target.request().header("If-None-Match", response.getEntityTag()).get();
        //same result 
        //response = target.request().header("If-None-Match", response.getEntityTag().getValue()).get();
        Assert.assertEquals(eTag, response.getEntityTag());
    }

// the following code always throws an exception inside of org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java class:
    private char getNextCharacter(boolean skipWhiteSpace) throws ParseException {
        ....
        // this line of code always throws it:
        if(this.index >= this.length) {
            throw new ParseException(LocalizationMessages.HTTP_HEADER_END_OF_HEADER(), this.index);
        } else {
            return this.header.charAt(this.index);
        }
    }
```

I run tests via arquillian, dependency versions:

```
<!--Arquillian JUnit integration: -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--glassfish-embedded:-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

How can I resolve it? How can I send a request with "If-None-Match" header inlcuded and don't get an exception?

**EDIT**:
In order to avoid the error, I had to use wildfly embedded application server instead of glassfish.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem with the code you provided. Though I wasn't using your same test container. I was simply using Jersey Test Framework. I wonder if the test container has anything to do with it.

Comment: @peeskillet, ok, thank you. Now I try to use wildfly embedded container instead of glassfish, but, unfortunately it's much harder to configure it and run.